# How can I get the value of a html <button> (I'm not submitting any forms)?

Tags: php, html, button

Basically, I am generating a random number between 1 and 10 and assigning that to $b. I then have if statements for each possible number (1-10) that will all print a button with the corresponding value ($b).

```
$b = rand (1,10);
if ($b == 1){
    echo "<button value = 1></button>";
}
if ($b == 2){
    echo "<button value = 2></button>";
} // etc.
```

If 2 buttons with the same value are pressed, I want to set $match == true, else false.
How can I get the value of every 2 buttons that are pressed?
(I am able to code in html and php, but am willing to learn jQuery/Javascript if those two languages are relevant to this problem)

Thanks!

Comment: Your code isn't valid PHP, and how can you press TWO buttons at one time?

Comment: First of all, you need to give your button an ID attribute.  Secondly, you should not need any IF statements at all, but should be able to insert the value of $b into the echoed string.

Comment: Sorry :/ I meant that the user presses one, then another.
-
Ok, that makes sense. So would it be echo "<button id = $b></button";

Comment: You don't have to have all those if statements. You can just do     `echo "<button value=$b></button>";`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I have read your question correctly. However I have created a jQuery solution that seems to do what you are asking. It creates 10 buttons, each with a unique value. A click function then checks if a button has been clicked twice. If so, an alert is displayed.

```
//create 10 buttons
for(var i = 0;i<10;i++){    
    $('body').append('<button id="' + i + '">Button' + i + '</button>');
}

//set a default button id to compare with clicked button
var buttonID = 0;

//button click function
$('button').click(function(){
    //get the id of this button
    var thisID = $(this).attr('id');

    //see if this value is the same as the last button clicked
    if(thisID == buttonID){
        //do things
        alert('Same button pressed');
    }

    //update last button clicked
    buttonID = thisID    
});
```

jQuery is quite easy to pick up, especially if you are already familiar with php. There are certainly a lot of resources available to help you along the way.

The example - http://jsfiddle.net/fytjD/1

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm, kind of. What I wanted was basically pairs of buttons with the same ID. (2 buttons with ID of 1, 2 buttons with ID of 2, etc. ) When those 2 buttons were clicked one after the other, they would "do things". 
Thanks for your help (:

Comment: Also, is there a way to randomize the buttons (so they aren't in order from 0-9)?
I created another ten buttons just by copying and pasting the first part of your code, so it works if 2 buttons with the same value are clicked one after the other, but how can I not display the alert if the user clicks the exact same button twice.
I'm sorry if this isn't making any sense. :/

Comment: well you will need to use class values not unique ids, or some other attribute. and create two buttons at a time instead of one. Randomizing the buttons is a bit more tricky. You could use css to position the buttons by referencing the class name.